# Error: Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"" or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "<" found

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to Solve This Problem in React Native? 
I used This Command:
`react-native link` for linking `react-native-vector-icons`

**My Error:**

```
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"", or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "<" found.
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"", or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "<" found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my Android SDK path in local.properties file and Solved
my path was: `sdk.dir = C://Users//USERNAME//AppData//Local//Android//sdk`

- in Windows

  sdk.dir = C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk
- in macOS

  sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
- in linux

  sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk

Replace USERNAME with your user name

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution was in the git lines that added to my info.plist file under ios/projName.

there were merge conflicts which was showing "<<<<<<"

when I resolve them, everything goes well!

PS. Make sure to check all of your changed files. these "<<<<" may be on other files, too!